# String Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm facing a problem with my binary search tree. After add in all the String value, I am able to search what I have searched before. But, it cant retrieve the value stored in tree.right(or tree.left). Even if my tree.right have the value, but when I search it, it will return "Record Not Found". Output and Code shown below:

```
  public void add(String value) {  
      if(value.toLowerCase().equals("red") || value.toLowerCase().equals("green")  || value.toLowerCase().equals("blue") || 
            value.toLowerCase().equals("yellow") || value.toLowerCase().equals("black")) {
         if (root == null) {
            root = new StringTreeNode(value.toLowerCase());
            size ++;
        }
        else
            addleaf(root, value.toLowerCase());
    }

}


public void addleaf(StringTreeNode branch, String value) {
    if(value.compareTo(branch.data) < 0) {
        if (branch.left == null) {
            branch.left = new StringTreeNode(value);
            size ++;
        } else
            addleaf(branch.left, value);
    } else if (value.compareTo(branch.data) > 0) {
        if (branch.right == null) {
            branch.right = new StringTreeNode(value);
            size ++;
        } else
            addleaf(branch.right, value);
    } else {

    } 
}

public void searchNode (String value) {
    found = false;
    if(root == null)
        System.out.println("Nothing here");
    else
        searchBranch(root, value.toLowerCase());
    if (!found)
        System.out.println("Records not found.");
}


public void searchBranch (StringTreeNode tmp, String value) {
        if(value.equals(tmp.data)) {
            System.out.println("Records found, " + value + " exist in search history!");
            found = true;
        } else if (tmp.left != null)
            searchBranch(tmp.left, value);
        else if (tmp.right != null)
            searchBranch(tmp.right, value);
}
```

**Output**

> What do you want to search?(0 to exit) :  red
>
> What do you want to search?(0 to exit) :  green
>
> What do you want to search?(0 to exit) :  blue
>
> What do you want to search?(0 to exit) :  yellow
>
> What do you want to search?(0 to exit) :  black
>
> What do you want to search?(0 to exit) :  0
>
> Tree Value :   red  green  blue  black  yellow
>
> Stack Value : 
>   1. black
>   2. yellow
>   3. blue
>   4. green
>   5. red
>
> What do you want to search for the existence history?(0 to exit) : 
>   red
>
> Records found, red exist in search history!
>
> What do you want to search for the existence history?(0 to exit) : 
>   green
>
> Records found, green exist in search history!
>
> What do you want to search for the existence history?(0 to exit) : 
>   blue
>
> Records found, blue exist in search history!
>
> **What do you want to search for the existence history?(0 to exit) :  yellow
>
> Records not found.**
>
> What do you want to search for the existence history?(0 to exit) : 
>   black
>
> Records found, black exist in search history!

I am curious although "yellow" is added into tree, but "yellow" is not in my search result.

Comment: Hi, Jin. Check what other people have already done: https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/blob/master/src/data-structures/tree/BinaryTreeNode.js. Hope it can help. But please add more detail on your development environent, e.g. **Java** version.

Comment: Thx for helping me, will look through that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `searchBranch` method is using the wrong criteria to decide which child branch to search.  It should be comparing `tmp.data` to `value` to decide between the left and right branches, not just going down whichever branch happens to lead somewhere:

```
public void searchBranch (StringTreeNode tmp, String value) {    
    if(value.equals(tmp.data)) {
        System.out.println("Records found, " + value + " exist in search history!");
        found = true;
    } else if (value.compareTo(tmp.data) < 0)
        searchBranch(tmp.left, value);
    else 
        searchBranch(tmp.right, value);
}
```

Notice that this is basically the same logic that `addLeaf` uses when deciding whether a given `value` belongs in the left or right branch of a node.